# begin/end form makes textfield inputs unfillable

Tags: debugging, bugs, fill

I noticed a weird behavior on Latex using Overleaf. The below code produces this result, according to overleaf output:

[image: overleaf output]

But if I download and open the pdf using acrobat reader I see that some textfield inputs are not fillable:

[image: pdf output]

If I open the pdf using a browser, all the text fields are fillable, but when I save the pdf, these fields are not saved.

I managed to find the solution to this issue, it is to remove the begin/end form around the `LOCKBIT is "0xFF:`. So it will be:

```
.....
\begin{document}

\CheckBox{LOCKBIT is "0xFF: }  

\begin{tabular}{| c | p{2.7cm} | c | p{2.7cm} | c | p{2.7cm} |}
.....
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the begin/end form be independent from the textfields below them?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,2pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,booktabs,array}
\usepackage[headheight=2pt,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}% read the console - fandyhdr tells you what value you need for consistent layout!
\usepackage{hyperref}% load last unless you know a package should be loaded later


\begin{document}


\begin{Form}
    \CheckBox{LOCKBIT is "0xFF: }       
\end{Form}

\begin{tabular}{| c | p{2.7cm} | c | p{2.7cm} | c | p{2.7cm} |}
    
    \hline
    kpHbeforedec(56): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.1, width=\linewidth]{} 
    & kpHafterdec(57): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.1.1, width=\linewidth]{}
    & KpHDiv(58):
    & \TextField[name=T4.1.2, width=\linewidth]{}\\
     \hline
    kiHbeforedec(72): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.2, width=\linewidth]{} 
    & kiHafterdec(73): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1, width=\linewidth]{}
    & KiHDiv(74):
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.2, width=\linewidth]{} \\
     \hline
    kdHbeforedec(88): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.3, width=\linewidth]{} 
    & kdHafterdec(89): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.3.1, width=\linewidth]{}
    & KdHDiv(90):
    & \TextField[name=T4.3.2, width=\linewidth]{}\\
     \hline

\end{tabular}

\subsection{PID cooling}

\TextField[name=T4.2.1.0]{CoolingAvailable(59):}

\begin{tabular}{| c | p{2.7cm} | c | p{2.7cm} | c | p{2.7cm} |}
    
    \hline
    kpCbeforedec(8): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.1, width=\linewidth]{} 
    & kpCafterdec(9): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.2, width=\linewidth]{}
    & KpCDiv(10):
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.3, width=\linewidth]{}\\
     \hline
    kiCbeforedec(24): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.4, width=\linewidth]{} 
    & kiCafterdec(25): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.5, width=\linewidth]{}
    & KiCDiv(26):
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.6, width=\linewidth]{} \\
     \hline
    kdCbeforedec(40): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.7, width=\linewidth]{} 
    & kdCafterdec(41): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.8, width=\linewidth]{}
    & KdCDiv(42):
    & \TextField[name=T4.2.1.9, width=\linewidth]{}\\
     \hline

\end{tabular}

\subsection{Overheating protection}

\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
    ProtectionTempMax(12): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.4, width=\linewidth]{}\\
     \hline
    ProtectionTempMin(28): 
    & \TextField[name=T4.5, width=\linewidth]{}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Timing target}

\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
    TargetReachedThreshHold(11):
    & \TextField[name=T4.3.1.1, width=\linewidth]{}\\
    \hline
    CloseToFinalTargetDelay(27):
    & \TextField[name=T4.3.1.2, width=\linewidth]{}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Sensors Configuration}

\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
    OnlyOneTemperatureSensor(2):
    & \TextField[name=T4.4.1, width=\linewidth]{}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Components versions}

\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
     PCB Version(48):
     & \TextField[name=T4.5.1, width=\linewidth]{}\\
     \hline
     F/W Version(64):
     & \TextField[name=T4.5.2, width=\linewidth]{}\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use simply only one `\Form` at the begin of the document. That is an initialization command, not something that goes around some fields (I don't know why it was implemented as environment, it only confuses people, https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/151)

Comment: Though it's clear to me, what your question is, please follow Ulrike's advice and reduce both your code and example to the absolut necessary to reproduce your problem. Thanks

Comment: Beside this: don't use periods in the names. From the pdf spec: "The period is used as a separator for fully qualified names and a partial name shall not contain a period character."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use periods in field names. They have a special meaning:

> the PERIOD is used as a separator for fully qualified names, a partial name shall not contain a PERIOD character

If I replace all of them by hyphens

```
& \TextField[name=T4-2-1-1, width=\linewidth]{}
```

it works:

[image]

Comment: Oh that was it..  all right, thank you!

Comment: On this point... LaTeX (hyperref package) might be able to check if the name is valid before generating PDF, but that's nontrivial. Or at least warn the user in the documentation (on the other hand if the user doesn't know what "name" is they probably won't use it anyway)

Comment: Okay actually `name` is useful, different label should have different name [Is this a hyperref forms bug? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/is-this-a-hyperref-forms-bug)

Comment: @user202729 testing for the period is easy, and l3pdffield-testphase does it and errors:  `! Package pdffield Error: The field name `abc.blub` contains a period.`. But hyperref is old and it doesn't support all aspects.

Comment: well as long as it's maintained by someone it could/should be updated...

Comment: @user202729 if you want to, sent me a pull request. I will not extend the hyperref code myself. It will stay as it is as legacy code. People who are not satisfied with the options of hyperref should switch to the new code.